# how to concatenate multiple variables and strings

Tags: variable

I am trying to form a url parameter (for Google Maps API) from entry field data. Basically, this is what I would like to do:

```
{% set street = entry.address %}

{% set  city = entry.city %}

{% set urlParam = street.", ".city.", UT"  %}
```

Is this possible with Twig and, if so, what is the proper syntax for concatenating multiple variables and strings?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify the title to say something along the lines as to where you are try to do this, such as "in a template".

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to use the [twig join filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/join.html):

```
{% set urlParam = [street, city, 'UT']|join(', ') %}
```

[join](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/join.html) concatenates the items in the sequence with the separator of your choice in between.

Comment: For things like addresses I usually use `|filter|join(', ')` so there are no repeated commas if any of the fields are null or empty.

Comment: Thanks, Marion - that seems to make a lot more sense than my approach!

Comment: mark me correct?

Answer (score 8):

Figured it out!  Proper syntax is:

```
{% set urlParam = street ~", " ~city ~", UT"  %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add another example to this since this post help point me in the right direction.

In my example, I am getting back a list of events from a 3rd party. All that is returned to me is the slug. But, you can see that I wanted the url to be prepended with `/event-results/`.

```
<a href="{{ url('/evnet-results/'~event.slug) }}">{{ event.title }}</a>
```